# Namespace not available and replaced with .GlobalEnv

Tags: r

When running pre 4.0 code, i got this message (in german).

```
  Warnung: Namensraum ‘gamlss.dist’ ist nicht verfügar und ist durch.GlobalEnv ersetzt worden während Objekt ‘mod_gam’ verarbeitet wurde
```

Translation:

```
"Warning: Namespace "gamlss.dist" is not available and is replaced by .GlobalEnv, while object "mod_gam" was processed."
```

I reinstalled gamboostlss, gamboost, and mboost, but this warning is still there. How can i get rid of it, and can i trust the calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a problem of variable inside `.RData` file in your working directory. This file contains all your data, variables and objects created during the R session. As you work, this data is stored for the next session. If you have your data stored in e.g. CSV and don't need to store session data, you can delete the RData file completely and let RStudio create a new one (see e.g. [here](https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/rdata-files.html)).

If you need this session data, but you have source data to create a new `mod_gam`, you can remove the object `mod_gam` by running `rm(mod_gam)` from your R console. Note this will delete your object from the RData file, so you'll need to run your code again to create a new `mod_gam`.

This should work, hope it helps.